# PHP / REST - How do I implement a role based access of my API?

Tags: php, rest, rbac

I have started a PHP project (A Project Management Item Tracking Tool) using an API centric approach and have made a fairly good start.

I have created 2 `GET` the methods so far I want to restrict access but don't know where to start.

*In the context of my database*

- `Project` is the container that encapsulates different actionitems.
- `Actionitems` are 'assigned' to a `user`.
- `Users` exist in a database.
- `Roles` as assigned to a user.    (`User`, `Admin`, `Super`)

---

- User can only update their own item
- Admin had create and update privilege
- Super has total administrative privilege

---

> **My question is:**  Where should I start in PHP to only allow
>   accessing the api via proper users, either via a login api, or some
>   other means?  Any help to get started would get me going.

To start I have successfully created an endpoint to access access resource (actionitems) using a JSON string to test the response.

**Existing Endpoints I want to restrict**

```
GET /api/actionitems/
```

With a general structure to access specific resources within a table as follows:

```
GET /api/actionitems/4
```

Note additional api endpoints should be accessed as follows

each route as up to 3 route tokens *(following the /api/)*

```
GET /api/users/123/actionitems   (get all actionitems for user 123)


GET /api/users/123/actionitems?<more-filers> applies further filtering
```

Comment: What do you mean by restricting endpoints?

Comment: Though my question is placed, I want to know if I should defer the process of role based access until all endpoints are created.   I might be going out of order right now.

Comment: I want to essentially, prevent any general guest,client from making api calls that could alter the database, or retrieve results that are not supposed to be served to them unless logged in with with the right privilege.

Comment: Are you using some other language on front end? You could make the user login and make them to pass a token(probably a JSON Web token) whenever they are making an API call. So, if they hit an API without the token, you return a 401 response.  Regarding role based access, I would have let them make an API call and then check in my backend as to whether they have access or not and return a 403 response accordingly.

Comment: Thank You, Yes, I have a simple AngularJS front end on a separate directory from the API in my project directory.   Since HTTP is stateless, how do I keep track of the login on the server without passing around $_SESSION or how do I keep state.  Do I have to keep state?

Comment: Once logged in, send the token to the Angular frontend. Then, you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) on the front end to preserve the `auth_token` and send it in every request to the server by doing `localStorage.getItem('auth_token')`. Server  will process the token and move forward accordingly.  [This can help](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle **authentication** and **authorization** for your APIs.

These are very basic steps to understand the solution:

- Client calls login API using user credentials(username, password).
- Server **authenticates** user credentials and generates a token.
- Server stores this token in database against authenticated user id and responds to client.
- Server already has authorization role rights to access different APIs associated with this authenticated user in database.
- Client calls resource APIs using token provided by login API.
- Server verify token in database and fetch user and user role rights against this token for authorization.
- Resource APIs **authorize** and provides required data or perform actions according to authenticated user role rights.

There are multiple ways to achieve this in standardize way:

- [3 Common Methods of API Authentication Explained](https://nordicapis.com/3-common-methods-api-authentication-explained/)
- [JSON Web Token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token)
- [oAuth2.0](https://oauth.net/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at JWT tokens
https://jwt.io/

Here's some quick informations

- An API with a token is stateless, you have to send the token on every request , generally in the Authorization Header, the token can contain a payload with some data like the user id the creation and expiration time.
- On the server side, when you receive a token with a request you can just find the user id inside the payload and find the corresponding user in the database.
  Since the token cannot be modified without the private key you can trust the data you receive.
- Then you can just check if the user has some Admin or Super admin roles or if the item belongs to him and send the correct response.

Note: The payload inside the token is public meaning that everyone can read it, don't put any sensive informations.

If you want to use some long term authentication you can use refresh token with jwt tokens, they are stored in the database and can be used to create a new jwt token.

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thank you Jordan,  I have started with the tutorial of rest api authentication using JWT to get me going:  https://www.codeofaninja.com/2018/09/rest-api-authentication-example-php-jwt-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

### User Access Restrictions

There are several possibilities for restricting user access. Here are some of the simplest methods:

1. Adding [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/middleware#main-content)
2. [Gates](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#gates)

### For the Middleware

You can protect a route or a group of routes by adding middleware.
For more information, you can refer to the Laravel documentation.

For example, you can protect a route like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    // ...
})->middleware('web');
Or you can group routes with middleware like this:

Route::middleware(['web'])->group(function () {
    // ...
});
```

### Gates

In your case I will tell you why you should use Gates.

To restrict access to your API endpoints in your PHP project, you should consider using an authentication and authorization system. One way to achieve this is by implementing an API Gateway or middleware, such as Gate, that handles user authentication and authorization. Here are some reasons why you should use Gate for this purpose:

1. **Fine-Grained Control**: Gate allows you to define complex access control rules based on user roles, which aligns well with your requirements. You can specify who can access which API endpoints and what actions they can perform.
2. **Scalability**: As your project grows, managing authentication and authorization becomes more complex. Gate provides a scalable solution for handling access control that can adapt to your evolving needs.
3. **Security**: Security is crucial when managing access to your API. Gate helps you secure your endpoints, protecting sensitive data from unauthorized access.
4. **Simplicity**: Gate simplifies the process of defining and enforcing access control rules in your PHP project. You can define policies and roles, making it easier to manage access at a granular level.
5. **User-Friendly**: Gate can help you create user-friendly error messages or responses when users try to access restricted endpoints. This can enhance the user experience by providing clear feedback.

Here's a general approach to get started with Gate:

1. **Define Policies**: Create policies that specify what actions are allowed for each user role. For example, create policies for "User," "Admin," and "Super" roles that define which API endpoints they can access and what actions they can perform.
2. **Authenticate Users**: Implement a user authentication system, which could involve a login API or other authentication mechanisms. Upon successful login, you can assign a role to the user based on their credentials.
3. **Check Permissions**: In your API endpoints, use Gate to check if the authenticated user has the necessary permissions to access a particular resource or perform a specific action. You can apply these checks in your API routes or controllers.
4. **Handle Unauthorized Access**: When a user tries to access an endpoint without the required permissions, return an appropriate error response, such as a 403 Forbidden status code, and provide a clear message explaining the reason for denial.

By using Gate or a similar access control system, you can implement secure and organized access control for your PHP project, making it easier to manage who can access your API endpoints and what they can do with the data. It will also help you maintain the security and integrity of your project as it continues to evolve.

Laravel provides a powerful way to handle permissions using gates.
You can create gates and their policies to control who can do what. Gates allow you to manage access rights, for example:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Update the given post.
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Post $post): RedirectResponse
    {
        if (Gate::forUser($user)->allows('update-post', $post)) {
            // The user can update the post...
        }

        if (Gate::forUser($user)->denies('update-post', $post)) {
            // The user can't update the post...
        }

        // Update the post...

        return redirect('/posts');
    }
}
```

You can also throw exceptions based on gate checks. What's interesting about gates is that you can manage the views for users.

For example, you can send all users to the super admin to view all users. If a user is an admin, you can show them all users except those with higher roles, effectively excluding super admins. Gates can be a powerful tool when used effectively.

By utilizing gates and policies, you can finely control user access to your Laravel application.
It's a versatile and robust approach to handle permissions and access restrictions.

Keep in mind that gates can provide even more functionality, but I'll leave it to you to explore further in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#gates)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34290068)